# Handling missing and null parameters in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to asp.net mvc.

now the requirement is that I have to handle following URLs in same ActionResult

if HTTP//jpripu/Handset/shop_code=&hosho_date= then do something.

if HTTP//jpripu/Handset/shop_code=Cust01&hosho_date=20131212 then do something

if HTTP//jpripu/Handset/hosho_date= then do something

if HTTP//jpripu/Handset/shop_code= then do something

Is it feasible to execute above conditions separately?
could anybody help me on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean URLs like `http://jpripu/shop_code=&hosho_date=20130923`
then this controller is for you:

```
    public class HandsetController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index(string shop_code, string hosho_date)
        {
            ViewBag.shop_code = shop_code;
            ViewBag.hosho_date = hosho_date;

            return View();
        }
    }
```

Note: Index - is default Action, defined in your routing.

Also I suggest [Pluralsight Introduction to ASP.NET MVC 3](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/pluralsight-introduction-to-aspnet-mvc-3) screencasts as a quick-start quide to ASP.NET MVC.